# ChartJS multiple doughnut chart issue when data is low

Tags: angular, chart.js

I am trying to create multiple doughnut chart using chartJS. Issue is when there is single element and data is low, graph looks weird as per attached image

[image]

but when there is high data (>50) chart looks good.
[image]
[image]

I have attached stackbliz link to check code.
https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-cxy7kn?file=src%2Fmain.ts